# SUM values of all entries' cost column matching a list of items

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's my sheet setup:

- I have a sheet "**Inventory**" that holds rows of all my inventory items in stock. Every item has a value/column for "**Cost**", and a column for "**Sale Price**".
- I have another sheet "**Photography**", that will have ***for every row/entry*** a cell which specifies which are the list of items used in the photo, referenced by some inventory `item ref`. And from that I want to `vlookup` or something, to fetch the "Cost" of all those items in the list, and SUM them up.
- That way I can know for a specific photo, what are all the items used in the photo, and how much is the cost of all those items (summed up).
- Then I will do the same for the "Sale Price", that way for every photo I take, I'll be able to tell the cost of that product item "as is" (with all the different inventory items), and the sale price.

***Example:***

[image]

I was able to do that for only 1 item, but I want the formula to work on the "list" of items in B9.

I even tried with this query formula, I just didn't know how to say "matching any item from the list", which will be a string in another cell:

```
=SUM(QUERY(A:B,"select B where A matches 'ID-100'"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "items used" column consistently uses comma-space separated format for item lists, the following will work.

```
=query(Cost!A:B, "select sum(B) where A = '" & join("' or A = '", split(B9, ", ")) & "' label sum(B) ''")
```

Here, `split` splits the list of items used into individual item Ids. These are then joined by putting `' or A = '` in between, for example:

```
ID-101' or A = 'ID-101
```

There are bits prepended and appended to form the query string, e.g.,

```
select sum(B) where A = 'ID-101' or A = 'ID-101' label sum(B) ''
```

which does the job. The label part is necessary to get one-cell output, without a "Sum(Cost)" header getting in the way.

---

A detail concerning split: as written above, `split(B9, ", ")` splits by *either* comma or space (ignoring empty string in the output). So it will work even with `ID-1,ID-2, ID-3 ID-4`. On the other hand, this may be a problem if your IDs contain spaces. The stricter splitting mode is `split(B9, ", ", False)` which requires the whole string ", "   to be used as a separator.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!